# Responsive bootstrap 4 footer

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm struggling to figure out why my 3-column footer isn't displaying each column on top of each other on small screens like phones. It's a Drupal subtheme built using the Barrio theme

Layout HTML

```
<footer class="site-footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="site-footer__top clearfix">
      <section class="col region region-footer-first"></section>
      <section class="col region region-footer-second"></section>
      <section class="col region region-footer-third"></section>
    </div>
   </div>
 <footer>
```

CSS (stripped of unrelated stuff like colors etc.):

```
footer {display: block;}
.container {padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0;}
.site-footer__top {display: flex;}
.col {flex-basis: 0; -ms-flex-positive: 1; flex-grow: 1; max-width: 100%;position: relative; width: 100%;}
```

I was under the impression, that the `.col` class was enough to get the desired behaviour as explained [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) and I can't see any issues in the CSS.

Can you see why my code doesn't behave in the desired way?

Best,

Comment: Checking, but it seems like you a missing a closing div in the snippet.

Comment: Thanks, that was a manuel mistake when creating the post. It's there alright

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why my 3-column footer isn't displaying each column on top of each
> other on small screens like phones.

Try following for mobile view

```
footer {
    display: block;
}
.container {
    padding-left: 0; 
  padding-right: 0;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 678px) {

  .site-footer__top {
    display: flex;
  }
  .col {
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pukf14yd/2/)